# regex to match all elements inside string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want to get all strings between brackets `[]`.
i tried regex match methode and it's not working

i only get the first element changed

here is my code

```js
tags = "[r,a,9]@[r,a,8].com".match(/([(?:[??[^[]*?]))/);
for (let index = 0; index < tagNumber; index++) {
  console.log(tags[index]);
  fromName = "[r,a,9]@[r,a,8].com".replace(tags[index], "haha");
}
```

Comment: So in this input case you want regex that will find the two strings "r,a,9" and "r,a,8"?

Comment: You need the `g` modifier in the regexp to return all matches.

Comment: What is `[??` supposed to mean in the regexp?

Comment: You need to escape `[` to match it literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/\[.+?\]/g`

`/` denotes the start of the pattern

`\[` matches the `[` character

`.+?` matches any character, 1 or more times, lazily

`\]` matches the `]` character

`/g` denotes the end of the pattern and to find ALL matches

```js
const input = "[r,a,9]@[r,a,8].com"
const pattern = /\[.+?\]/g

const tags = Array.from(input.match(pattern))
console.log(tags)

const fromName = input.replace(pattern, "haha")
console.log(fromName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `[` and `]` to match them literally. There's no need for the capture group around everything.

Add the `g` modifier to match all the occurrences in the string.

```js
tags = "[r,a,9]@[r,a,8].com".match(/\[[^[]*?\]/g);
let tagNumber = tags.length;
for (let index = 0; index < tagNumber; index++) {
  console.log(tags[index]);
  fromName = "[r,a,9]@[r,a,8].com".replace(tags[index], "haha");
  console.log(fromName)
}
```

You can use a regular expression in `replace()` to replace all the matches at once.

```js
fromName = "[r,a,9]@[r,a,8].com".replace(/\[[^[]*?\]/g, "haha");
console.log(fromName)
```